# MongoDB Aggregations - Is it possible to get matching values instead of sum, count, avg etc

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

See the document below,

```
 [
     {

        "memberId": "m1",
        "positionId": "pos1",
        "projectId": "prj1"
    },

    {

        "memberId": "m1",
        "positionId": "pos2",
        "projectId": "prj1"
    },

    {

        "memberId": "m1",
        "positionId": "pos3",
        "projectId": "prj2"
    },

    {

        "memberId": "m1",
        "positionId": "pos5",
        "projectId": "prj2"
    },

    {

        "memberId": "m2",
        "positionId": "pos3",
        "projectId": "prj2"
    }
]
```

I need to generate an output, for a given  *memberId*, 
group by *projectIds* and return with associate *positionId*s for that *projectId*

Say,

```
{
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : {
            "project" : "prj2",
            "position" : ["pos5", "pos3"]
        }
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : {
            "project" : "prj1",
            "position" : ["pos2","pos1"]
        }
    } 

]}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongo : Group and push more than 1 element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292434/mongo-group-and-push-more-than-1-element)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push) operator to create your compound `_id` field. The best thing to do is [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) by "projectId' and return "position" as array.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { '$group': {
        '_id': '$projectId', 
        'position': { '$push': '$positionId' }
    }}
])
```

Which returns:

```js
{ "_id" : "prj2", "position" : [ "pos3", "pos5", "pos3" ] }
{ "_id" : "prj1", "position" : [ "pos1", "pos2" ] }
```

*But if you really feel the need to have a compound `_id` field you need one more [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) stage.*

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { '$group': {
        '_id': '$projectId', 
        'position': { '$push': '$positionId' }
    }},
    { '$group': {
        '_id': { 
            'project': '$_id', 
            'position': '$position'
        }
    }}
])
```

Which yields:

```js
{ "_id" : { "project" : "prj1", "position" : [ "pos1", "pos2" ] } }
{ "_id" : { "project" : "prj2", "position" : [ "pos3", "pos5", "pos3" ] } }
```

Answer (score 0):

This aggregation could help, its result is the same as the output you have mentioned.

```
db.test.aggregate(
   [
      {
        $group : {
           _id : {"project" : "$projectId"},
           position: { $addToSet:"$positionId"  }
        }
      }
   ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match:{"memberId" : "m1"}},
  {$group:{_id:"$projectId", positions:{$addToSet:"$positionId"}}},
 {$project:{_id:0, "project":"$_id", positions:1}}
])
```

### OUTPUT

```
{
"result" : [ 
    {
        "positions" : [ 
            "pos5", 
            "pos3"
        ],
        "project" : "prj2"
    }, 
    {
        "positions" : [ 
            "pos2", 
            "pos1"
        ],
        "project" : "prj1"
    }
],
"ok" : 1
```

}